# How to print an Object in Dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dojo

How can I print all information e.g. for the Mouseevent object in Dojo. I tried this:

```
myObject = {
    id: "myObject", onClick: function(evt) {
    dojo.byId("objectPrint").innerHTML = dojo.toJson(evt);
    }
};
```

I have a div container that has the id objectPrint. But it doesn't work.

Comment: 'doesn't work' does not help us. What is the error?

Comment: on firebug the error message "Can't serialize DOM nodes" appears.

Comment: @Haniball: What line? Dude, don't make me work for you.

Comment: line 14 in dojo.xd.js it seems that there is a problem with serializing the object to json. When I replace "=dojo.toJson(evt)" with "=evt" I get "[object MouseEvent]"

Comment: Isn't the error clear? You cannot serialize DOM nodes. They can contain circular references and such...

Comment: ok. That I cannot serialize DOM nodes is clear to me. But isn't there a way to print the actual condition of the MouseEvent object?

Comment: What do you want to do? If it is only for debugging purpose, then use `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` which expects a text string in valid HTML format?   Yours is not valid HTML -- it is JSON.

For FireFox, you'll need to use `textContent`.

DOM event objects contain the `target` property which points to a DOM node.  dojo.toJson() is used to serialize a JavaScript hash object, and you can't use it to serialize a DOM node.

You probably should be building your own hash object for dojo.toJson() in order to look at the event object:

```
... = dojo.toJson({ 
             target: evt.target.id, 
             clientX: evt.clientX, 
             clientY: evt.clientY,
                 :
      });
```

However, this is a very convoluted way of doint it.  Better to use `console.log`.